# Can I "use" Java 8 with Android Development now?

Tags: java, android, java-8

I currently have Java 7 JDK installed. It's been like that for awhile. However, recently, my professor is instructing the class to uninstall Java JDK 7 and install Java JDK 8 instead to be able to work on homework and such.

I've been using Java JDK 7 to write and deploy Android apps without any problems so I'm wondering if it's safe to make the upgrade now the JDK 8? I'm assuming that I won't be needing any Java 8 specific methods or functions in my Android development. So if I stay away from that, will my Android development be at all affected?

On a side note, I haven't been able to find any official documentation that states whether or not Java JDK 8 is safe or not or how to make it safe. Either way, I'm going to have to upgrade to Java 8 soon...

Comment: Android doesn't support most of Java 8's new features.

Comment: So if I don't use any of those new features, I'll still be able to compile and run my code?

Comment: Even if you install JDK8, you can set the compatibility to 1.7 (Or whichever is required)...

Comment: better keep both 7 and 8.

Comment: Got it! I will make note of it.

Comment: [Oracle has stopped providing dowload link to JDK7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've been using Java 7 to deploy Android apps then it's certain, up to this point, you haven't used any Java 8 features so I don't see how it would matter.

Follow your instructor's directions and when you do an assignment for school simply select either the JDK or Language Level in the Project Structure.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, select `Project`

You can default to the Java 8 SDK but limit it to Java 7's features for your Android apps. Or you can simply set your homework projects to the Java 8 SDK.

*Going out on a limb here assuming Android Studio includes the core settings of Intellij.*

Answer (score 17):

In Google I/O 2016, they announced that Android now supports some features of Java 8, but not all the features.

Features like

- Default and static interface methods
- Lambda expressions (also available on API level 23 and lower)
- Repeatable annotations
- Method References (also available on API level 23 and lower)
- Type Annotations (also available on API level 23 and lower)

Additionally, the following Java 8 language APIs are also available:

- Reflection and language-related APIs

  - `java.lang.FunctionalInterface`
  - `java.lang.annotation.Repeatable`
  - `java.lang.reflect.Method.isDefault()`
  - and Reflection APIs associated with repeatable annotations, such as `AnnotatedElement.getAnnotationsByType(Class)`
- Utility APIs

  - `java.util.function`
  - `java.util.stream`

All what you should do is to use the new jack compiler, to do this you have just to add this to your gradle file `build.gradle (Module: app)`:

```
android {
  ...
  defaultConfig {
    ...
    jackOptions {
      enabled true
    }
  }
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

**References:**

- https://developer.android.com/guide/platform/j8-jack.html
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B08iLAtS3AQ&feature=youtu.be&t=28m14s

Answer (score 3):

It's safe if you don't use the java 8 features.

although you may be keen on java 8 with retroLambda and collectionsQuery.
https://github.com/evant/gradle-retrolambda and
https://bitbucket.org/mart_bogdan/collectionsquery/src

This will allow you to write your code to something like the following: -

```
mButton.setOnClickListener( v-> doClickEvent()); 

mView.postDelayed( () -> someMethodToRun() , 1000);

Queryable.from(listOfObject).forEachR(r -> doProcess(r));
```

as opposed to the clunky

```
mButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener(){
     @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
         doClickEvent();
      }
});
```

to use java 8 with retrolambda just add in the gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {

    // :
    // Snips the rest of configuration.
    // :
    compileOptions {
        encoding "UTF-8"
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'  

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1' 

    compile 'com.innahema:collections-query:0.2.9'
}
```

and at the project gradle.build file add the following...

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'

        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
        classpath 'me.tatarka.retrolambda.projectlombok:lombok.ast:0.2.3.a2' //fix lint issue

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess you should just give it a try. On a side note: You can easily run JDK 7 and JDK 8 side by side. I don't know about Android Studio, but in Eclipse you can configure the build path.

Despite that: Are you using Java 8 specific features for your homework? If you don't use lambdas or JavaFX 8, I don't think you *will need* JDK 8. Sounds more like your professor just wants to use the latest version of Java (judging from your first sentence).

Comment: My professor hasn't given too many details yet other than noting that he prefers we have JAVA 8 to avoid "potential issues" in the future.