# Use Java SE 8 with Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8

I cannot use Java 8 new features (especially the new date classes) in Android Studio.

I changed `JDK Location` in `Project Structure` to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73`, I even changed the `JAVA_HOME` and `PATH` variables. But I cannot find the package `java.time.chrono`.

What am I missing ?

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780565/can-i-use-java-8-with-android-development-now)

Comment: I tried most of the instructions there and I can't find a way to work with the new packages...

Comment: Android's runtime is not Java's runtime...